# How can I get access to the HttpRequestMessage in Ninject?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject

I currently have filters and message handlers that add values to the request properties (i.e. via `HttpRequestMessage.Properties.Add`). I'd like to use these values in constructor injection of my controllers using Ninject. How can I access the current request object using Ninject?

In ASP.NET MVC, I was able to use `HttpContext.Current` in a `Kernel.Bind<>().ToMethod()` anonymous function. Web API doesn't have a static state object and I'd like to avoid creating one.